# contacts_service : await ContactsService.getContacts() too slow in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

While using below code for fetching the contact from android device, it is taking too time to list the contacts.Is there any solutions recommended.

```
getContacts() async {
var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
setState(() {
    _contacts = contacts;
  print("Contact List " + contacts.toList().toString());
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the speed by setting the "withTumbnails" parameter to false, which in default is set to true

replace:

```
List<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
```

with

```
List<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false);
```